# Why is this excel conditional formatting rule removing the cell gridlines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

See what's happening to the cells gridlines (or border?):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apJvr.png]

Here is the rule:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBIQP.png]

[image: https://ibb.co/hYhk9mC]

This is the rule that is activating it, and it doesn't make sense to me because the fill color is 'no color'. I could see if I was doing a fill color of white (that can remove the gridline from a cell), but I'm not.

Comment: Why do you have that first rule? The format that you're setting is the default format of the sheet (no fill). So, just delete the first rule.

Comment: Because when the cell is blank (contains "" due to IFERROR statement replacing !DIV/0 error with "") my other rule activates and highlights the cell red (no idea why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the first rule and change the other rules to use formulas.

Like this:

```
=AND($D1>0.4,$D1<>"")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to Excel so I need to learn about this more, but thanks for solving the problem!

Comment: Don't worry about it. What you did was perfectly reasonable. It doesn't make sense that the red rule should highlight the cell when it's empty. I replicated the same issue so decided to revert to a formula. Generally, I try to use a formula whenever I use conditional formatting as you have more control. You just need to write something that evaluates to true or false depending on the inputs, then the format is applied when it's true.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably got the "pattern style" or "pattern color" set.

With the empty pattern set and "no fill" selected I get the behaviour you are seeing. Hit the "clear" button in the bottom right to clear it.

A "pattern" will be two colours. The colour you selected as the background (no colour is still an active colour apparently) and that "no fill" colour is, with a clear pattern, the same as "filling" the cell with whatever the sheet background colour is.

You are still applying some kind of fill and so the cell borders disappear.

My advice below about using proper cell borders still stands. This is not an issue if you explicitly set up borders yourself.

---

Because you have not explicitly set up borders and grids for cells.

By default those cell borders are "phantom" borders and will be hidden when a cell is filled by formatting or conditional formatting. You can test it by manually applying a fill to a cell. Irrespective of whether the format is conditional or not an unset "phantom" border will disappear.

If you want or need cell borders shown then you should select that range and apply actual cell borders to the range.